# cannot seem to get mapbox for xamarin forms working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, maps, mapbox

the nuget packedge for xamarin forms mapbox was recently updated to the latest version and i was trying to use it by using the code they provided but cannot seem to get it to work.(github => https://github.com/NAXAM/mapbox-xamarin-forms)

[image: mapbox code and errors]
i added identical code as the demo and cant seem to find any stuff the pertains to the Ifeature or all the other stuff giving errors in the github and there arent any nuget dependencies within the mapbox xamarin forms packedge that i can find that fix the problem either. any help would be greatly appreciated. the errors are basically just saying those things just dont exist. and the github documentation from my understanding does say how to implement those features

errors

[image]

[image]

```
using GeoJSON.Net.Geometry;
using Naxam.Controls.Forms;
using Naxam.Mapbox;
using Naxam.Mapbox.Layers;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Comment: Do you install from NuGet and then use the code in a new project? Could you provide the error mesage with code?

Comment: I guess it caused by using wrong assembly. Download all the library in the github and then add reference of the project you downloaded.

Comment: @wendyZang added the errors and the nuget packedges i to for mapbox such as Naxam.MapBox.Forms , GeoJSON.Net and it also uses newtonsoft.json . and what do you mean by download all the libary in git hub you mean redownload it or get a new xamarin forms mapbox packedge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved. the github info they were using for the front was outdated and i found the info inside the demo folder.

Comment: @wendyZhang yeah sorry i try to but stack overflow doesnt let me for 1-2 days and i forget